# Why can't a direct proof be made backwards?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Say we have the following implication:

$$\textit{Let $x\in \mathbb{Z}$. If  $5x-7$ is even, then x is odd. }$$

The method used by my book to prove this implication is by means of a proof by contrapositive. But what prevents me from saying:

$$ \textit{Assume that x is odd. Then: } x=2k+1, \textit{and we have}: 5(2x+1)-7 =10x-2=2(5x-1).$$
$$\textit{Since  $5x-1$ is an integer, $2(5x-1)$ is even. Ergo, $5x-7$ is even when x is odd.}$$

Comment: you mixed up your $k$ and $x$ in the middle there, but the big difference between direct proof and proof by contrapositive is what it is you are trying to prove and what you take as a hypothesis.  For $P\Rightarrow Q$, you take $P$ as a hypothesis for direct, and for contrapositive you take $\sim Q$ as the hypothesis.  It doesn't make one proof any more correct than the other, but you will find several proofs later on which are much easier to approach from a particular direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've shown that if $x$ is odd, then $5x-7$ is even, but that is not what you were supposed to show.  You were supposed to show that if $5x-7$ is even, then $x$ is odd.

To see the problem with your method, let's use your method to prove this very similar statement:

> Let $x\in \Bbb Z$.  If $4x-2$ is even, then $x$ is odd.

Your method now goes like this:

> Assume that $x$ is odd.  Then: $x = 2k+1$, and we have $4(2k+1) -2 = 8k+2 = 2(4k+1)$.
>
> Since $4k+1$ is an integer, $2(4k+1) $ is even, Ergo, $4x-2$ is even when $x$ is odd.

So it looks okay, right?  But “If $4x-2$ is even, then $x$ is odd.” is *false*, because $4x-2$ is even whether or not $x$ is odd.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you! I knew my question would turn out to be rather silly, but for some odd reason I couldn't figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Luke I'm glad I could help.  You should also observe that the last statement in your proof is “$5x−7$ is even when $x$ is odd” but you were asked to prove “If $5x-7$ is even then $x$ is odd” which does not say the same thing.  Your proof of “$5x−7$ is even when $x$ is odd” is flawless, but it wasn't what you were asked to prove.  “If… then” and “when” are not the same.

Comment: I see - you'd end up having to write "If x is odd, then 5x-7 is even.", and that is quite clearly the converse of the implication I was supposed to prove (which means I end up proving a different statement altogether). Thanks!

Comment: Yes, exactly so.

Comment: Hey, I'd just like to follow up with another quick question. Let x be an integer. Prove that 3x+1 is even if and only if 5x-2 is odd. Obviously, we'd need to define short lemmas to prove this, and then prove each implication (P->Q and Q->P). Instead of proving lemmas "If 3x+1 is even, then x is odd" and "If 5x-2 is odd, then x is odd", could I just prove one lemma: "3x+1 is even if and only if x is odd"? It's obvious I could use that on the first implication: "If 3x+1 is even, then 5x-2 is odd", but could it be used on "If 5x-2 is odd, then 3x+1 is even"? Is that backwards again, or ok?

Comment: The phrase “$A$ if and only if $B$” is short for “if $A$ then $B$, and if $B$ then $A$”, so you don't have to worry about getting it backwards.  “If and only if” works in both directions at once.

Comment: I figured, but would my proposal be correct? Because to prove a biconditional, one has to prove both implications its made of. One of two implications in the biconditional above is If "5x-2 is odd, then 3x+1 is even". Calling the first part P and the second Q, we now have an implication of the form $P \Rightarrow Q$. It doesn't seem right to me that I could use my lemma to prove this, as my lemma says "3x+1 is even if and only if x is odd", which only says something about statement Q. I don't see how I could apply that lemma to the aforementioned implication ($P \Rightarrow Q$).

Comment: I thought your idea was to show that $5x-2$ is odd (“$A$”) if and only if $x$ is odd (“$X$”), and $3x+1$ is even (“$B$”) if and only if $x$ is odd (“$X$”).  Then you want to show $A\iff B$, and instead you show $A\iff X$ and $X\iff B$.  Then $A\implies X$ (because $A\iff X$) and $X\implies B$ (bceause $X\iff B$), so $A\implies B$.  And $B\implies X$ and $X\implies A$, so $B \implies A$.

Answer (score 1):

But then you are not proving the original implication: you are proving its converse.

Answer (score 1):

You have shown that $5x-7$ is even when $x$ is odd, but this does not show that it is only even when $x$ is odd - it could also be even when $x$ is even (as for example $6x-8$ would be).

Your "proof" would go through for $6x-8$ but it would not be true that if $6x-8$ is even then $x$ is odd.